# Arrayformula to lookup last entry

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have this example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xK86N1P2UMcY7WwHcwVV24ECk7caMbAxXvnDeKwBLYA/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to have the data in column D filled in with arrayformula. The value should be the value in column B.

I've tried using combination of `ROW&INDIRECT&FILTER&QUERY|VLOOKUP` , but it didn't work, as if ROW() cannot be used in arrayformula. Maybe you guys have some idea that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C7:C="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(A7:A), IF(B7:B<>"", {ROW(A7:A), B7:B}), 2, 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, thanx!